# Pyqt5 QTreeWIdgetItem with select one item checkbox at atime

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a QTreeWidget and each QTreeWidgetItem has 3 checkboxes.I would like to do two things but I can't figure how to do them.

1. The user should be able to select only one check box at time for
   each  QTreeWidgetItem.So the selection of a given checkbox of a
   QTreeWidgetItem should deselect the other checkboxes of that
   QTreeWidgetItem.
2. The selection/deselection of a given parent QTreeWidgetItem checkbox
   should select/deselect all its child checkboxes in the same column.
   Below is my code:

Any help would be highly appreciated

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
import sys

def main():
    app     = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tree    = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
    tree.resize(500, 200)
    headerItem  = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
    item    = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
    tree .setColumnCount(4)
    tree .setHeaderLabels(["pluto", "X", "Y", "Z", ""])
    for i in range(3):
        parent = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
        parent.setText(0, "Parent {}".format(i))
        parent.setCheckState(1, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.setCheckState(2, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.setCheckState(3, Qt.Unchecked)
        #parent.setFlags(parent.flags() | Qt.ItemIsTristate | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        for x in range(5):
            child = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
            child.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            child.setText(0, "Child {}".format(x))
            child.setCheckState(1, Qt.Unchecked)
            child.setCheckState(2, Qt.Unchecked)
            child.setCheckState(3, Qt.Unchecked)


    tree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well, you could start by connecting to the [`itemChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged) signal to do both: you just have to do anything whenever the [`checkState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#checkState) of the item/column is `Checked` and then proceed to uncheck the other siblings and just check the child at that column: that will automatically trigger the same for all child and grandchild elements.

Comment: I have tried doing something like child.itemChanged.connect(self.boxSelected) but i get the error: "AttributeError: 'QTreeWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'itemChanged'"

Comment: Why would you connect to the item? Besides the fact that items are *not* QObjects (so they don't have signals), you should connect to the signal of the table widget.

Comment: I have tried both ItemChanged and ItemClicked but both of them only correctly detect the selection of a qtreeWidgetItem and not the check box.So if I click on one item but then click the checkbox of another item,the currentItem is always the one i clicked on and not whose checkbox I selected

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem by using itemClicked.Here is my solution incase someone is interested.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
import sys

class treeManagement:
    def __init__(self):
        app     = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.tree    = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.resize(500, 200)
        headerItem  = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
        item    = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
        self.tree .setColumnCount(4)
        self.tree .setHeaderLabels(["pluto", "X", "Y", "Z", ""])
        for i in range(3):
            parent = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
            parent.setText(0, "Parent {}".format(i))
            parent.setCheckState(1, Qt.Unchecked)
            parent.setCheckState(2, Qt.Unchecked)
            parent.setCheckState(3, Qt.Unchecked)

            for x in range(5):
                child = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
                child.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                child.setText(0, "Child {}".format(x))
                child.setCheckState(1, Qt.Unchecked)
                child.setCheckState(2, Qt.Unchecked)
                child.setCheckState(3, Qt.Unchecked)

        self.tree.itemClicked.connect(self.checkboxSelectionChanged)
        self.tree.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def checkboxSelectionChanged(self,selectedItem, selectedColumn):
        print(selectedItem.text(0))
        print(selectedColumn)
        # In this method I manage checkbox selected

        if selectedItem is None:
            return

        # 0-The item is unchecked.
        # 1-The item is partially checked. Items in hierarchical models may be partially checked if some, but not all,
        # of their children are checked.
        # 2-The item is checked.

        sumCheckState = selectedItem.checkState(1) + selectedItem.checkState(2) + selectedItem.checkState(3)

        state = QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
        for i in range(1, 4):
            if selectedColumn != i:
                if sumCheckState >= 4:  # Prevent update if user clicked in the space near checkbox or there's only one
                    # checkbox currently checked in this row
                    selectedItem.setCheckState(i, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            elif selectedItem.childCount() > 0:  # selectedColumn=i
                for j in range(selectedItem.childCount()):
                    child = selectedItem.child(j)
                    for k in range(1, 4):
                        if selectedColumn != k:
                            if sumCheckState >= 4 or (sumCheckState == 2 and child.checkState(k) == QtCore.Qt.Checked
                                and selectedItem.checkState(selectedColumn) != QtCore.Qt.Unchecked):
                                # Prevent update if user clicked in the space near checkbox or there's only one
                                # checkbox currently checked in this row
                                child.setCheckState(k, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                        else:
                            child.setCheckState(k, selectedItem.checkState(selectedColumn))
            elif selectedItem.parent() is not None:
                # I have clicked on a child element so no parent should be in checked state
                if sumCheckState >= 4:  # Prevent update if user clicked in the space near checkbox or there's only one
                    # checkbox currently checked in this row
                    for i in range(1, 4):
                        selectedItem.parent().setCheckState(i, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t=treeManagement()
```